# Combinatorics, dividing objects into groups.

Tags: combinatorics

Assuming we have got 5 horses, that are competing in a race, and assuming 2 different horses can arrive at the exact same time. 
How many possibilities there are for outcomes? for 3 horses for example :

1st place:horse1   horse1 horse2 horse2 horse3 horse3

2nd place:horse2   horse3 horse1 horse3 horse2 horse1

3rd place:horse3   horse2 horse3 horse1 horse1 horse2

1st place : {horse1 horse2}{horse2 horse3}{horse3 horse1}

2nd place : {horse3}       {horse1}       {horse2}

1st place : {horse1}       {horse2}       {horse3}

2nd place:  {horse2 horse3}{horse1 horse3}{horse1 horse2}

1st place :{horse1}{horse2}{horse3}

So all in all 13 possibilities for 3 horses. my question is : how many for 5 horses?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there are $n$ horses, the number of ways would be the sum of $k! \cdot S(n,k)$ for $1 \le k \le n$ where $S(n,k)$ is the Sterling number of the second kind, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind). For $5$ horses this gives $541$ ways.

Note that $S(n,k)$ counts the number of partitions of the $n$ horses into $k$ unlabeled sets, so must be multiplied by $k!$ because we want to consider which horses are in which place in the race.