# How many different probabilities are there?

Tags: probability

i have this problem, i couldn't find any way to solve it, please help!
the problem:
there are 5 men.
In a Men-Race, the result is submitted by the ranking of each man, 1st place, 2nd place, 3rd,4th and 5th place.. (as they cross the finish line).
its possible that 2 men (or more) can cross the finish line at the exact same time, in a result, they will be in the same place together as a group (the group arrangement from the inside doesn't matter, for example, participants (bob,mark,james,carl,sam) bob 1st, (mark-james-carl) 2nd, sam 3rd.. this example is the same as this: bob 1st, (james-mark-carl) 2nd, sam 3rd so it counts as 1 as in this example the "2nd place" is the "group")

in a "3 Men-Race" the answer is 13  (13 different results)..

how many different results are there in a "5 Men-Race"? *hint: the answer's sum of digits is 10.
someone answered me that the answer is 631 (6+3+1=10), he didn't tell me why, please explain.. thanks a lot!!

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1040951 for a similar question.

Comment: Thank you very much! But does it also answer the question if there are 3 "horses" or even 4, that arrive at the same time?

Comment: @BukLau Yes, that answer does allow for any number of "horses" to come in at the same time. I don't know why the digit sum happens to be 10... possibly a coincidence, put as a hint for some reason by whoever asked the question.